# CDC filtering by datetime get error. An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, cdc

Folowing `fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn` function for filtering change history by datetime. 
Sql example from msdn but with my table:

```
DECLARE @begin_time DATETIME, @end_time DATETIME, @begin_lsn BINARY(10), @end_lsn BINARY(10); 
SET @begin_time = GETDATE()-1
SET @end_time = GETDATE()+1; 
SET @begin_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('smallest greater than', @begin_time);
SET @end_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('largest less than or equal', @end_time);
SELECT * 
FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_EXT_GeolObject(sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('smallest greater than', @begin_time), sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('largest less than or equal', @end_time),'all')
```

I print all variables and see folowing resul:

```
Aug  9 2017 11:41AM
Aug 11 2017 11:41AM 
@begin_lsn = 0x0000002B000000CE007B
@end_lsn = 0x000000E000002CA00001
```

But in this case i get folowing error:

> An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or
>   function cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_ ... .

Sql works without errors if not using `fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn` function. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_EXT_GeolObject(sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_EXT_GeolObject'), sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn(), 'all')
```

In this case `@begin_lsn = 0x000000440000001000AC` and `@end_lsn = 0x000000E000002D960001`

I don't understand where is bug...
What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: The error messaging in CDC is… not the best. I've seen this error before when the time boundaries are not correct somehow. What happens when you look at `sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('smallest greater than', @begin_time` and `sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('largest less than or equal', @end_time)` directly? How do they compare with the min and max LSNs?

Comment: Hm. I can't find this function. All what i see it is `fn_cdc_get_all_changes_TableName` and `fn_cdc_get_net_changes_TableName` functions.

Comment: I copied the above from your code (the parameters to cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_EXT_GeolObject). What I'm asking is for you to manually inspect what LSN values are being passed to the CDC function to make sure that they make sense.